# Find integral, what's wrong with these 2 solution?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, delay-differential-equations

I am meeting an interesting problem and solved two different method.

Could you see following 2 solution, and find errors?

> **QUESTION.**
>   $$    f(x)=2x^3 -2x^2 - \int_{0}^{x+1}f(t)dt  $$
>
> where $f(x)$ is symmetric about the point $(1,0)$
>
> and differentiable at all point.
>
> Find $$    \int_{2}^{4}f(x)dx  $$ .

$$ $$

**Sol.1**

By the SYMMETRIC about $(1,0)$, we get $f(1)=0$ $  \    \  $$    $     $\cdots(a)$

From $    f(x)=2x^3 -2x^2 - \int_{0}^{x+1}f(t)dt  $

$\Longrightarrow$  $f'(x)=6x^2 - 4x -f(x+1)$

$\Longrightarrow$ $f'(0)=-f(1)=0 $ $  \    \  $ (by (a).)

$ $

By the SYMMETRIC about $(1,0)$,  $f'(0)=f'(2)$.

$\Longrightarrow$ $0=f'(0)=f'(2)=6  \cdot2^2 -4\cdot2-f(3)=24-8-f(3)=16-f(3)  $

Thus $f(3)=16$.

$ $

From $   f(x)=2x^3 -2x^2 - \int_{0}^{x+1}f(t)dt  $

$$\begin{align}
&  \Longrightarrow  16=f(3)=2\cdot 3^3-2\cdot3^2-\int_{0}^{4}f(t)dt =36-\int_{0}^{4}f(t)dt \\
&  \Longrightarrow  20=\int_{0}^{4}f(t)dt\\
\end{align}$$

$$$$

$0=f(1)=2\cdot1^3-2\cdot1^2  -   \int_{0}^{2}f(t)dt $

$ \Longrightarrow 0= \int_{0}^{2}f(t)dt $

$$$$

SO, 
$$ \int_{2}^{4}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{4}f(x)dx  -\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx  = 20-0=20 $$

$$$$$$$$

> > NOW, 2nd solution

$$$$
 **Sol.2**

$ \int_{0}^{2}f(t)dt = 0 $.

$ f(-1)=-4$.

By the SYMMETRIC about $(1,0)$, $  \   $   $f(3)=-f(-1)$.

So,

$$\begin{align}
 & 4 = -f(-1)=f(3)=2\cdot3^3-2\cdot3^2-\int_{0}^{4}f(t)dt\\
&  \Longrightarrow  32=\int_{0}^{4}f(t)dt\\
\end{align}$$

$$$$
Thus, $$ \int_{2}^{4}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{4}f(x)dx  -\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx  = 32-0=32 $$

$$$$ $$$$

> **Sol.1** and **Sol.2** say different things.
>
> What mistake led me this result?

$$$$

Thanks in advance.
$$$$

$\color{red}{\text{----------- **EDIT** ----- **Please read below, thank you** ---------------------------------}}$

$$$$
**P.S.1** 
 $$$$  Let me 'darely' DEFINE symmetric about point $(a,b)$
$$$$

If $f$ is symmetric about point $(a,b)$

if and only if

$f(x)+f(2a-x)=2b$

if and only if

$f(a-x)+f(a+x)=2b$

$$$$

**P.S.2**
$$$$
By **P.S.1**

$f'(x)=f'(2-x)$

So, $f'(0)=f'(2)$

$$$$

Comment: I didn't read all of it but at first you say $f(1) = 0$. But $f(-1) = - 2-2 = -4$ and not $f(-1) = 0$

Comment: @AndréSchemaitat: $f(-1) = -4$ is valid, what he means by saying that "$f$ is symmetric about the point $(1; 0$)" is that $(1; 0)$ is the point of symmetry of the graph of $f$ (not $(0; 0)$ as you might've thought).

Comment: I don't know but $f$ seems to be ill-defined, i.e. there's no such $f$, and hence you can deduce many things from this ill-defined $f$.

Comment: @user143993 Can you please explain exactly what you mean by "$f(x)$ is symmetric about the point $(1,0)$."

Comment: @cpiegore $$$$  Let me 'darely' DEFINE symmetric about point $(a,b)$
$$$$

If $f$ is symmetric about point $(a,b)$
$$$$
if and only if
$$$$
$f(x)+f(2a-x)=2b$
$$$$if and only if
$$$$
$f(a-x)+f(a+x)=2b\\$$$$$

Comment: Okay. Then just ignore my comment.

Comment: @user143993 I think you are correct since your definition includes odd functions as a special case.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2: Ok,first I apologize for what I wrote.. It seems that I understimated the problem.. Here is what I've done:

The simetry with respect to $(1,0)$ traduces in $$f(x+1)=-f(-x+1) $$(#). Just replacing in the equation that defines $f(x)$(call it equation (1)) we get $f(-1)=-4$. By the simmetry, $f(3)=4$, too. Replacing in (1), we get $\int_{0}^{4} f(t) dt =32$. Now, using that $f$ is differentiable in all of R, we can use the chain rule in (#), giving $$f'(x+1)=f'(-x+1)$$. Deriving (1), we get $$f'(x)=6x^2-4x-f(x+1)$$. Evaluating in $2$, we get $f'(2)=12=f'(0)=-f(1)=\int_{0}^{2} f(t) dt$.

Finally,$$\int_{2}^{4} f(t) dt=\int_{0}^{4} f(t) dt-\int_{0}^{2} f(t) dt=32-12=20$$.

Concerning your solutions: About the first, I don't know where do you get from that $f(1)=0$. In the second I don't get $\int_{0}^{2} f(t) dt=0$. I think you are asuming that $(1,0)$ belongs to the graph of $f$, but it's not necessary.

Comment: HOW do we know $f(3) = f(-1)$ or $f(1) = 0$ or anything else about the function $f$?

Comment: As far as I can see the ONLY value that we know with any certainty is $f(-1) = -4$.

Comment: @cpiegore: Because the OP stated that $(1; 0)$ is the point of symmetry of the graph of $f$.

Comment: @Diego Can you explain how "$f(x)$ is symmetric about the point $(1,0)$" implies $f(1)=0$ because I really don't get it.

Comment: @cpiegore I think $$ $$ $f$ is symmetric about point $(a,b)$
implies
$f(x)+f(2a-x)=2b$ or $f(a-x)+f(a+x)=2b$
$$$$
So, $f(1-x)+f(1+x)=0$
Thus, $f(3)=-f(-1)$ $$$$

Comment: @Diego
I don't think $f(x)=x^2$ is proper example. $ $ Because $f(x)=x^2$ isn't symmetric at any point.
$ $
It is just symmetric y-axis.

Comment: @Diego  I added my question for your opinions, please check my question bottom (P.S.). Really thank you

Comment: @Diego I think...$$ $$ $f$ is symmetric about $(a,b)$ and differentiable $$$$ implies $$$$ $f'$ is symmetric about $x=a$ (the line)$$$$(Please check bottom of my question.)$$$$

Comment: Thanks for your answering. You wrote $f(x+1)=-f(-x+1)$. NOW insert $x=0$, we get $f(1)=-f(1)$. SO $f(1)=0$

Comment: And then insert x=1 at equation (1), we get `integral from 0 to 2` is 0

Comment: $f(x+1)=-f(-x+1)$ should work for every x except 0. So I don't think that f(1) =0 for the reasons you give. Nevertheless, I think that for f to be continuous and simmetric with respect to (1,0), it has to be f(1)=0. That could be the reason why yo get 20 too.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=2x^3 -2x^2 - \int_{0}^{x+1}f(t)dt \text{ solving this for } \int_{0}^{x+1} f(t) dt \\ \int_0^{x+1} f(t) dt=2x^3-2x^2-f(x)  \\ \text{ Evaluating } \int_2^4 f(t) dt= \int_0^4 f(t) dt- \int_0^2 f(t)dt \\ =(2(3)^3-2(3)^2-f(3))-(2(1)^3-2(1)^2-f(1)) \\ =(36-f(3))-(0-f(1))\\ =36-f(3)+f(1) \\ =36-f(3)+0 \text{(since } f(1)=0 \text{ is given } \\ \\ \text{ time to play with } f(3) \\ \int_0^{0} f(t) dt=2(-1)^3-2(-1)^2-f(-1) \implies 0=-2-2-f(-1) \implies f(-1)=-4 \\ \text{ and we know } f(3)=-f(-1) \text{ since } f \text{ is point symmetric about } (1,0)   \\ \text{ so we were almost done earlier and now we can finish } \\ \int_2^4 f(t) dt=36-f(3)+0=36-f(3)=36-4=32\\  $

Comment: If someone already posted this I didn't see this answer very clearly... But I don't think we need any differentiating.

Comment: I give up, I can't find any mistake in your answer, but neither in mine. Anyway, I think yours is more straightforward, and then probably the right one.....

Comment: @randomgirl At first, thanks for your answering. If you think your answer is correct(actually I think you are right!),,, why don't you check Sol.2 in my origin question?

Comment: I just wanna know ERRORS in Sol.1 / Sol.2...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there are 2 problems with your solutions.  First $f(x) = 2x^2 - 2x^3 - \int_{0}^{x+1} f(t)dt$ isn't really an algebraic equation, so you cannot expect to perform various algebraic manipulations on it and get a consistent answer.  Second it isn't clear what you mean by "$f(x)$ is symmetric about the point $(1,0)$."

If you differentiate the formula for $f(x)$ you get the differential equation $f'(x) = 6x^2-4x-f(x).$  Its solution is $f(x) = ce^{-x}+6x^2-16x+16$.  Using $f(-1) = ce+38 =-4$ we have $c = -42/e$.  Now we can integrate directly to find that $\int_{2}^{4}f(x)dx = -42e^{-3}+42e^{-5}+48$

Comment: When you differentiate,you should get f(x+1).

Comment: @cpiegore I added my question for your 'second opinion -not clear symmetric- ', please check about.. Really thank you.

Comment: @cpiegore You may as well solve differential equation about $f'(x)=6x^2 - 4x -f(x+1)$ rather than $f'(x) = 6x^2-4x-f(x).$ $$$$ Because $$f(x)=2x^3 -2x^2 - \int_{0}^{x+1}f(t)dt
\
\Longrightarrow
\
f'(x)=6x^2 - 4x -f(x+1)$$

Comment: @cpiegore$$$$ (might sound like stupid thing...) Is there anyting to do with between [not algebraic equation] and [may not performing some algebraic manipulation]? - about 1st problem you thought - $$$$

Comment: @user143993 I only said that because I didn't understand how you were getting $f(1) = 0$ or $f(3) = 16.$ Since you have explained what you meant by symmetry your solutions make more sense now.