# Help in differentiable equation $f'(x)=6x^2 - 4x -f(x+1)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> I am struggling with my first question, [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664250/find-integral-whats-wrong-with-these-2-solution) (concerned  with integral)

During fighting this problem, I met differentiable equation

**$$  f'(x)=6x^2 - 4x -f(x+1)$$**

$$$$
I can solve solve the equation $f'(x)=6x^2 - 4x -\color{purple}{f(x)}$ not hardly...

BUT how can I solve the eqation **$ {f'(x)=6x^2 - 4x -\color{purple}{f(x+1)}}$**?

$$$$
I've already knocked 'wolframalpha.com ' - but not helpful-

[wolframalpha says... :-(](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%27(x)%3D6x%5E2%20-%204x%20-f(x%2B1))

$$$$

Comment: This is called a delay differential equation.  They are very difficult to s e analytically, but this one fortunately has a guessable solution.  Try something quadratic in $x$ added by an exponential.

Comment: @Paul We must have very different definitions of "solving". I'd expect it to mean finding all solutions and not just one.

Comment: @Gitgud maybe that's why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer.  And why I said "a" solution, not "the" solution.

Comment: @Paul $  \    \ $ Do [something quadratic in $x$ added by an exponential] means $e^{x^2 +1} +3$ for example..?$$$$ If not,.. Could you SUGGEST any example [something quadratic...], please?$$$$

Comment: No, it would be something like $ae^{bx}+cx^2+dx+f$.

Comment: @Paul Ah-ha. Let me try about it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f$ is sufficiently differentialbe you can do following:

By differentiating the equation multiple times you can eliminate the $6x^2-4x$, and you'll get $$f''''(x) = -f'''(x+1). \qquad \qquad (*)$$

Now you can try to find a solution for $f'''$. Then you can go back by integrating this solution and choosing the integration constants according to the equations you've gotten when differentiating.

Here I have to admit that I do not know how to find all solutions to $(*)$. But if we rename $f''' = y$ then $(*)$ is equivalent to $y'(x) = -y(x+1)$.

With the ansatz $y = e^{ax}$ plugged in this equation, you will find that $(e^{-a}+a)e^{ax} \overset{!}{=} 0$. Therefore $e^{-a} = -a$ which implies $ae^a = -1$. This actually has a (complex) solution using the Lambert $W$ function $a=W(-1) \simeq -0.318 - 1.33i$.

This is also what you get when you use the suggestions in the comments, but here you see that it boils down to finding the solutions to $$y'(x) = -y(x+1)$$